# Tables and div elements are not centred in reveal.js

Tags: reveal.js

If I add the following slide into the default presentation provided by reveal.js, then the table is not centred.

```
  <section>
  <p>This is centred</p>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>This</td>
      <td>is</td>
      <td>not</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </section>
```

[image]

I can fix it by adding in padding, but this then becomes dependent on the screen size, and I am worried that when I go to present the screen will be a different size. There must be a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/62) and my testing, if you add the `reveal` class to your table, the newest reveal.js should center it.

```
  <section>
  <p>This is centred</p>

  <table class="reveal">
    <tr>
      <td>This</td>
      <td>is</td>
      <td>not</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </section>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best solution - the .reveal class brings with a lot of other cruft, which you may not want for the table.  In the end, I edited the CSS stylesheet (reveal.css) to add

  `table {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }`

Comment: The cruft was kinda part of it, @Ketil. That is, your solution works for centering but is brittle, in other words, you'll miss out if reveal.js starts using a super-interesting-meta-centering-hyper-dimensional-style. Also editing the library is not a good idea IMO.